# Cannot include header from another ROS2 package

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, include, header

I want to include the header file "cpp_pubsub/publisher_member_function.hpp" from my package "cpp_pubsub" into my other package "cpp_pubsub_2" but I get the following error:

```
fatal error: cpp_pubsub/publisher_member_function.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "cpp_pubsub/publisher_member_function.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I checked my spelling and also included this line in my package.xml from package "cpp_pubsub_2": `<depend>cpp_pubsub</depend>`. Do you know how to write a CMakeLists.txt so that I can include a header file from a different package?

My CMakeLists.txt from package "cpp_pubsub_2" look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(cpp_pubsub_2)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(cpp_pubsub REQUIRED)

# include_directories(include)

add_executable(talker2 src/publisher_member_function.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(talker2 rclcpp std_msgs)
# target_include_directories(talker2 PUBLIC
#   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
#   $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
# )

add_executable(listener2 src/subscriber_member_function.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(listener2 rclcpp std_msgs)
# target_include_directories(listener2 PUBLIC
#   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
#   $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
# )


install(TARGETS
  talker2
  listener2
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)
install(DIRECTORY
  config
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# ament_export_include_directories(include)
# ament_target_dependencies(talker2 rclcpp std_msgs cpp_pubsub)
# ament_target_dependencies(listener2 rclcpp std_msgs cpp_pubsub)
ament_package()
```

My CMakeLists.txt from package "cpp_pubsub" look like this:

````
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(cpp_pubsub)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

add_executable(talker src/publisher_member_function.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(talker rclcpp std_msgs)
target_include_directories(talker PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
)

add_executable(listener src/subscriber_member_function.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(listener rclcpp std_msgs)
target_include_directories(listener PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
)

install(TARGETS
  talker
  listener
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
install(DIRECTORY
  config
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
install(DIRECTORY
  include/
  DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# ament_export_include_directories(include)
# ament_target_dependencies(talker rclcpp std_msgs cpp_pubsub)
# ament_target_dependencies(listener rclcpp std_msgs cpp_pubsub)
ament_package()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference for a package with alot of header files used in other packages: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_util/CMakeLists.txt. Hopefully that helps you find your problem :-)

I glanced through your files and some things that I note, though unsure the specific issue

> ament_export_include_directories(include)

This probably shouldn't be commented out

> ament_target_dependencies(talker2 rclcpp std_msgs)

This appears to be missing `cpp_pubsub`, the package containing the header

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added cpp_pubsub to ament_target_dependencies and commented the ament_export_include_directories in but this did not solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

As per your CMakeLists.txt, it seems you have added `cpp_pubsub` to `find_package`, but not to your `ament_target_dependencies`

> ament_target_dependencies(talker rclcpp std_msgs)

try modifying it like so

> ament_target_dependencies(talker rclcpp std_msgs cpp_pubsub)

this will link the dependency to the executable, as `find_package` only *finds* it in your system.

For more info check here: [ament_cmake user documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I added cpp_pubsub to ament_target_dependencies but this did not solve this error. I also tried to export cpp_pubsub as a library and linked this library against my executables from cpp_pubsub2 with target_link_libraries(talker2 ${cpp_pubsub_LIBRARIES})

Comment: @Benno I overlooked this at the beginning, but after completing the tutorials you probably don't have a `.hpp` file to begin with as you only made a .cpp file. If you want to make includes, check out `.h` header files and standard C++ programming. Also, for better understanding, try including some other ROS library instead of a custom one.